# PHPUnit - assertCount() not returning same result

Tags: php, phpunit, functional-testing

I am using `assertCount()` method within my Symfony project and PHPUnit Functional tests. I was refactoring a method, and suddenly I does not work any more. But I am not sure what could be a problem.

I wanted to move my method that I am using multiple times from one class:

```
public function testPostSuccessful(): void
{
    ... 
    // rest of the request code //

    $response = $this->client->getResponse();
    $responseBody = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);

    $this->assertArraySimilar($this->expected, $responseBody["data"][0]);

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

And in my other method:

```
protected function assertArraySimilar(array $expected, array $array)
{
    // expected amount of key - value pairs are returned
    $this->assertCount(6, $array);
    
    ...
    // rest of the code //
}
```

This is throwing an error:

> ```
> Failed asserting that actual size 2 matches expected size 6.
> ```

But when I dump the result like:

```
var_dump(count($array));die;
```

I get: **int(6)**

*UPDATE: Also when I input 2 instead of 6, I got reverse error like:* **Failed asserting that 6 matches expected 2**

What could be the problem here?

This works! Why is this working example and above one is not.

```
$this->assertCount(count($expected), $array);
```

Comment: `$array` is not overridden in your code?

Comment: I think not as I tried var_dump in assertArraySimilar() method and it returns 6. @Syscall

Comment: `array` is it a generator or an array? What's a result of `var_dump($array)`?

Comment: It's an array. Result is: array(6) {
  ["element1"]=>
  string(98) "lorem ipsum"
  ["meta"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["author"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(12) "123-456-7890"
    } ... etc ... @Syscall

Comment: Also tired $this->assertEquals(6, count($array)); and again the same error.

Comment: Also when I input 2 instead if 6, I got reverse error like: Failed asserting that 6 matches expected 2. This is confusing. @Syscall

Comment: What is your version of PHPUnit? The called code for this assertion seems to be [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9.5/src/Framework/Constraint/Cardinality/Count.php#L61). You could try to check the same conditions to reproduce.